# IntelliJ IDEA: is there a way to format java code in a canonical way?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have two java source files. Both represent the same class (semantically), but they were formatted differently.

For example, one of them contains the following line:

```
return Boolean.valueOf(Boolean.getBoolean("abc"));
```

While in the second file it looks like 2 lines:

```
return Boolean.valueOf(
        Boolean.getBoolean("abc"));
```

In both cases, when I apply formatting (Ctrl+Alt+L), these lines do not change.

Is it possible to format them in some canonical way: that is, to get the same code if the only difference is formatting?

Equivalently: is there any way to remove all ignorable whitespace? Such a 'dried-out' program would then be easily restored using 'Reformat code'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this if you turn off "Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting | Line Breaks" in the Java code style settings.

Comment: Thank you both. I also had to put zeros in all 3 'Keep maximum blank lines' fields on 'Blank lines' tab to 'canonicalize' blank lines usage.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Settings > Ediotor > Code Style > java

in tab Wrapping and Braces uncheck `line breaks`

Apply and make `(Ctrl+Alt+L)` again.